# Corrupt files when uploading from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, file-upload, corruption

I'm converting powerpoint files to individual images, and the images that are produced end up corrupted when I upload from Node.

The npm modules I'm using are [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) and [node-form-data](https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data).

I upload a file from my Node app like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var FormData = require('form-data');

function processPresentation(fileName,fileLoc,userId,customerId){
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('my_file',fs.createReadStream(fileLoc));
    var options = {
        url: config.getConverter()+"?tenant="+customerId+"&author="+userId+"&name="+fileName+"&ext=ppt",
        method: 'POST',
        form:data,
        headers:{'x-auth-token':token,'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'}
    };

    request.post(options,function(error,response,body){
        console.log(body);
        if(error){
            console.log('error',error);
        }
        if(!response){

        }
        if(response.statusCode === 200){
            addPresentation(JSON.parse(body),userId);
        }
    });
}
```

And it goes through my conversion process, I get a file like this as output:

[image]

Here's what all this actually says, if you open the powerpoint file and look at the text:
http://pastebin.com/Dbh0JPKA

When I use Postman and upload the same file like this:

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: xxxx.xxxxxxxxxx.net?name=00a94ec9-8f70-4279-8972-f49935cda295&ext=ppt&tenant=543840f80019abda4937a9e2&author=543bef549f8d54a53a02f6d9
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
x-auth-token: 772a5c0c023a447f68a9ac4fb2bb4bd39bafeb16b753df2222ffc835750cbbe6a4ef9ee82fab0902f39bc26851016a873d44c91a64f67de5e10044ef0787cebe
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 74aff430-f6b8-c7cd-d477-b9cc35897bb7

undefined
```

I get output like this:

[image]

Which is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think that the problem is that you are sending mime/multipart encoded data and you just want to send the file as the raw body of the post. There are a couple ways to do this.

Option #1, **Stream the File**:

```
var options = {
    url: config.getConverter()+"?tenant="+customerId+"&author="+userId+"&name="+fileName+"&ext=ppt",
    headers:{'x-auth-token':token,'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'}
};

fs.createReadStream(fileLoc).pipe(request.post(options));
```

This technique is actually streaming the file as the raw post body for your request.

Option #2, **Read the File then Post**:

```
var options = {
    url: config.getConverter()+"?tenant="+customerId+"&author="+userId+"&name="+fileName+"&ext=ppt",
    headers:{'x-auth-token':token,'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'},
    body: fs.readFileSync(fileLoc)
};

request.post(options, callback);
```

Here you are reading the file into a string and posting it using the `body` option. This sets the post body raw rather than using a mime/multipart encoding as you get with `formData`.

Comment: Thank you!!  Option #2 works, but Option #1 doesn't.  I still get corrupt files with Option #1 and have no idea why... any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the require for form-data and just do this:

```
var options = {
    url: config.getConverter()+"?tenant="+customerId+"&author="+userId+"&name="+fileName+"&ext=ppt",
    method: 'POST',
    formData: {
        my_file: fs.createReadStream(fileLoc)
    },
    headers:{'x-auth-token':token,'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation'}
};
```

Important there is `formData` vs `form`

Comment: That gives me an `invalid request` from my server, because it expects an input stream, which it doesn't get when I do the code above.

Comment: Actually, my file was accidentally gutted. I restored it, and running this code now gives me a corrupt file with `----------------------------186177887193287547417109
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="6cbd90c5-9e73-439f-8eea-2af77d8e8fdd"` in the beginning of it, if you open the file with a text editor

Comment: Ah! You don't want form or multipart encoded data at all! I'll post a separate answer...

Answer (score 0):

Doing this fixed it:

```
var length = fs.statSync(fileLoc).size;
    console.log('length is',length);
    var req = request.post({uri: config.getConverter()+"?tenant="+customerId+"&author="+userId+"&name="+fileName+"&ext=ppt",
        headers:{
            'x-auth-token':token,
            'Content-Type':'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
            'content-length':length
        }
    });
    fs.createReadStream(fileLoc).pipe(req).pipe(process.stdout);
```